# Finding $3r^2 + rs - 2s^2 + 2r - 3s$ given that $r$ and $s$ are the roots of $x^2 + x + 7$

Tags: quadratics, factoring

Suppose $r$ and $s$ are the roots of $x^2 + x + 7.$ Then, find the value of $3r^2 + rs - 2s^2 + 2r - 3s.$

---

I wanted to try and find a relationship between $3r^2 + rs - 2s^2 + 2r - 3s$ and perhaps $r + s$ and $rs,$ but I can't seem to find a factorization that works. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: You may want to use $r^2+r+7=s^2+s+7=0$.

Comment: Substituting $r^2 = s^2 + s + 7 - r - 7$ gives $rs - r + s^2,$ and the opposite gives us $r^2 + rs - s.$ Where can I go from here?

Comment: Now, use $r^2 = -r-7$.

Comment: We get $-s - 7 + rs - r = 0$ and $-r - 7 + rs - s = 0.$ Than?

Comment: $-r-7+rs-s = rs-r-s+7$. You have the values for $rs$ and $r+s$.

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just substitute $r = a+ib, s = a-ib$ into your expression?

Comment: This is a valid way of proceeding, but more complex than necessary.

Comment: Because the point of the exercise is to use the formulas for sum and product of roots.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is $1$
$$ (x^2+x+7)=0~~~.…...\tag1$$ and $r,s$ is roots so $rs=7$, $r+s=-1$ this implies $s=(-1-r)$
Now \begin{align}
& 3r^2+rs-2s^2+2r-3s
\\&=3r^2+7-2(-1-r)^2+2r-3(-1-r)
\\&=3r^2+7-2(1+2r+r^2)+2r+3+3r
\\&=3r^2+7-2-4r-2r^2+2r+3+3r
\\&=r^2+r+8
\\&=(r^2+r+7)+1
\\&=0+1 \end{align}
Since $r$ is root of the equation so putting $x=r$ in equation (1) we got $r^2+r+7=0$.

Comment: Why the downvote? The formatting was outrageous but the method itself is cleaner than our discussion above.

Comment: It would be faster to insert expressions for both squares simultaneously, $$3(r^2+r)+rs-2(s^2+s)-(r+s).$$ Then insert $r^2+r=s^2+s=-7$ and the Viete identities.